# sending an email using html5 android webview

Tags: android, html, email, webview

I am trying to create application and the application will able to send email from the application from WebView android. the example of the code will be like

```
<a href="mailto:email@echoecho.com?subject=SweetWords">Send Email</a>
```

the code working fine in browser, but in the WebView in android itself, it shown that the action is not supported.So I wonder, is it possible to send an email using HTML only in WebView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will do the job in your webview client.

What it does :

1. First, parse the link, to detect if it's an mailto link or not.
2. Parse to get the arguments of the mailto link
3. Send the email in an intent, with the given argument of your mailto link

See below :

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url){
    String mailToRegexp = "mailto\\:([^?]+)\\?{0,1}((subject\\=([^&]+))|(body\\=([^&]+))|(bcc\\=([^&]+))|(cc\\=([^&]+)))*";
    Pattern mailToPattern = Pattern.compile(mailToRegexp);
    Matcher mailToMatcher = mailToPattern.matcher(url);
    if(mailToMatcher.find()){
        String email = mailToMatcher.group(1);
        String subject = mailToMatcher.group(4);
        String body = mailToMatcher.group(6);
        String bcc = mailToMatcher.group(8);
        String cc = mailToMatcher.group(10);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        intent.setType("message/rfc822");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, email);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, bcc);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, cc);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to override (in your webview class) shouldOverrideUrlLoading (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)) to parse mailto links and send intent to mail app.

If you are using cordova/phonegap, you need to import inAppBrowser plugin and add target="_system" to your links so they will get directed as an intent